# NaN? Why will the browser not read this as a number?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <span class = "apples"> 9 apples</span>
    <span class = "apples"> 7 apples</span>
    <span class = "apples"> 3 apples</span>
    <span class = "apples"> 6 apples</span>
    <span class = "apples"> 11 apples</span>

    <script>
    var apples = document.querySelectorAll('span.apples'),

    total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) 
    {
    total += parseInt(apples[i].textContent, 10);
    };
    document.write(total);
    </script>
```

Above I am attempting to pull all of the numbers from the span tags which have the classname "apples" and total the number of apples.
As it is, the code works successfully.

But if I place a - sign (negative sign) in the front of each number, it will come up as NaN.

The reason I am adding the - sign is because the span elements in this example is just a replica of the real span elements I am dealing with on my free forum at proboards, and the real span elements have - sign in the front of their numbers for some reason.
So when the code above didn't work on my forum and only returned NaN, I added - signs to the test span elements above and that also returned Nan. So it's something to do with the - sign. 
Here is what the real span on my forum looks like:

```
    <span class="viewing"> - 2 viewing</span>
```

Why is this NaN, and how do I get around it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `- 2 viewing` is not a number. If you remove the space, it becomes a number.

Comment: NaN = Not a Number, if you're receiving it, the parse function failed to convert to a number. You can permutate the string, or you can trim it to get the negative against the number, or you can fix your string. Many different solutions here.

Comment: I've posted an answer that should solve your problem, use my function and worry not :D

Comment: Have you considered using data-* attributes? Ex: `<span class="viewing" data-viewingcount="-2"> - 2 viewing</span>`? Then you can separate data used for calculations from the data used to display UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other saisd the issue is the fact parseInt sees the white space after the - and returns NaN like it is designed to do. So why don't you match the numbers with a regular expression.

```
var num = apples[i].textContent.match(/\d+/); 
num = num ? parseInt(num[0], 10) : 0;
total += num;
```

You can make the regular expression match a specific pattern if needed.

Comment: doesn't this leave out the value of the number if it is negative? shouldn't the regex be something like `var num = apples[i].textContent.match(/-?.\d/)[0].replace(/ /g,'');`

Comment: If the OP had negative numbers... In case here it is always a positive.

Answer (score 1):

Because `parseInt` doesn't like the space between `-` and `2`.

You get around it by not having the space, or by processing the contained text to remove stuff that isn't a pos/neg sign (and preferably letters).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space between the minus and the number:

```
parseInt("4");
4
parseInt("-4");
-4
parseInt("- 4");
NaN
parseInt(" -4");
-4
```

The parser probably expects a number after a minus sign and finds a space, making it a `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) says:

> NOTE parseInt may interpret only a leading portion of string as an integer value; it ignores any characters that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an integer, and no indication is given that any such characters were ignored.

So in your case it means that `parseInt` stops parsing string on the space after leading `-`. And since `-` itself is not a number you get `NaN` as the result.

In general I would recommend you to take another approach. Thus changing HTML to something like below would make your code much more robust and easy to maintain:

```
<span class="apples" data-number="9">9 apples</span>
<span class="apples" data-number="7">7 apples</span>
<span class="apples" data-number="3">3 apples</span>
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) {
    total += Number(apples[i].getAttribute('data-number'));
}
```

Now you can change representation (e.g. `apples (9)`) without worrying that it will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

**NaN** = *Not a Number*, if you're receiving it, the parse function failed to convert to a number. You can permutate the string, or you can trim it to get the negative against the number, or you can fix your string. Many different solutions here.

Use this function I threw together for you, should return numbers, with negatives as well.

```
function formatAndParseInt(string) { return parseInt(string.replace( /[^0-9,-]/g, '' )); }
```

conversly, if you want only numbers, and to discard any dashes (negative) then use this function

```
function formatAndParseIntAbs(string) { return parseInt(string.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' )); }
```